# Debug a long select statement

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I created a stored procedure that will:

1. Copy a table
2. Empty 8 tables
3. Copy the data from our production server back to our development server.

The whole procedure works except for this part:

```
INSERT INTO UserInformation (RequestType, RequestEffectiveDate, FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName, Location, Department, JobTitle, TemporaryEmp,  Vendor, UserID, Documaster, 
                ImageRight, Internet, RenewalDatabase, Email, Adobe, MapInfo, TrialWorks, Freedom, ISO, PolicyTerminator, CI, CIPreProd, ADPEZLabor, BUSUnderWriting, 
                WebPortalID, OFAC, WINSAccess, RequestedBy, RequestedDate, ReservePaymentAuth, DeptApprover, DepApprovalDate, ITApprover, ITApprovalDate, WINSPrimPolMgmt, 
                WINSPrimPremAcct, WINSPrimClaimMgmt, WINSPrimReinProc, WINSPrimMgmtInsInfo, WINSPrimMisc, WINSPrimPolInq, WINSPrimClaimInq, WINSPrimBillInq, WNPolMgmtBusOwn, WNPolMgmtBusAuto, 
                WNPolMgmtWrkComp, WNPolMgmtComUm, WNPolMgmtComPkgPol, WNPolMgmtComRec, WNPolMgmtPersRec, WNPolMgmtQuote, WNPolMgmtIssue, WNPolMgmtRenew, WNPolMgmtEndorse, WNPolMgmtCanNot, 
                WNPolMgmtFinCan, WNPolMgmtRein, WNPolMgmtRetro, WNPolMgmtRepEnd, WNPolMgmtNonMonEnd, WNPolMgmtAdd, WNPolMgmtChange, WNPolMgmtDelete, WNPolMgmtInquire, WNPolMgmtAddQuote, 
                WNPolMgmtAddCan, WNPrmAcctAccCurProc, WMPrmAcctChecks, WNPrmAcctDirBilProc, WNPrmAcctBillMaint, WNActCurProcControl, WNActCurProcEntry, WNActCurProcEntryAll, WNActCurProcLegal, WNActCurProcPrint, 
                WNActCurProcPost, WNActCurProcAdd, WNActCurProcChange, WNActCurProcDelete, WNActCurProcInquire, WNChkProcControl, WNChkProcEntry, WNChkProcPrCkEdLst, WNChkProcPrPstProdCk, WNChkProcPstManDiBil, 
                WNChkProcAcptCntrl, WNChkProcAcptEntry, WNChkProcPrtAcptCkEdLst, WNChkProcPstAcptCk, WNChkProcVoidStop, WNChkProcInvestigate, WNChkProcAdd, WNChkProcChange, WNChkProcDelete, WNChkProcInquire, 
                WNChkProcAcctCurr, WNChkProcDiBill, WNClmMgmtFstTrk, WMClmMgmtInClmEnt, WMClmMgmtClmEnt, WMClmMgmtAdjRes, WMClmMgmtChk, WMClmMgmtRec, WMClmMgmtLaw, WMClmMgmtDetClm, 
                WMClmMgmtArcExProc, WMClmChkMnIsPyCtl, WMClmChkMnIsPys, WMClmChkMnIsExCtl, WMClmChkMnIsExs, WMClmChkPrMnCkEdLs, WMClmChkPsMnChks, WMClmChkMaIsPys, WMClmChkMaIsExps, WMClmChkPrMaCkEdLs, 
                WMClmChkPrPsSyNmCks, WMClmChkPrPsPrNmChks, WMClmChkAcptCkCtrl, WMClmChkAcptCks, WMClmChkPrAcptCkEdLs, WMClmChkPsAcptChks, WMClmChkVdSpChks, WMClmChkCkInv, WMClmChkAutoAcptChks, 
                WMClmChkAdd, WMClmChkChange, WMClmChkDelete, WMClmChkInquire, WMReinPrcCoMaint, WMReinPrcIntMaint, WMReinPrcTrMaint, WMReinPrcPrgMaint, WMReinPrcCshCtl, WMReinPrcCshEntTr, 
                WMReinPrcCshEntFacPrm, WMReinPrcCshEntFacLos, WMReinPrcPrtReinCsh, WMReinPrcPsReinCsh, WMReinPrcOtReinPremEnt, WMReinPrcOtReinLosEnt, WMReinPrcAdd, WMReinPrcChange, WMReinPrcDelete, 
                WMReinPrcPrint, DateReqCreated, ReqCreatedBy, DateReqLastModified, ReqLastModifiedBy, UserPrimKey, CurrentLANID, CurrentWINSID, SpecialInstructions, VPNAccess, NCCIID, Virtru, MSAccessFull, 
                ISOClaimSearch, ISONet, ISOPassport, SanBornMaps, RProgramming, LexisNexis, Experian, WMClmMgmtAuth, WMClmMgmtLossCorr, GoogleEarth, Concur, 
                CutePDF, DIDyn, DIDNumber, Intern, PartTime, LeaveOfAbsence, PaymentAuth, PDErrorCorrect, EC500, PhoneBouncePattern, WebexMeetings, WebexTeams, BounceExtension,
                EC500Number, PowerBI, Tableau, UIPath, AllIN, RUR, ECase, ICInquiry, InvoiceExpenseAuth, International, DataHouseProd, DataHousePreProd, DataHouseTest, Zoom,
                PhysicalLocation, MSPowerApps, MSPowerAutomate, MSProject, MSVisio, Zendesk, Venminder, Snowflake, ImageRightPreProd, ImageRightTest)
    
    SELECT RequestType, RequestEffectiveDate, FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName, Location, Department, JobTitle, TemporaryEmp,  Vendor, UserID, Documaster, 
                ImageRight, Internet, RenewalDatabase, Email, Adobe, MapInfo, TrialWorks, Freedom, ISO, PolicyTerminator, CI, CIPreProd, ADPEZLabor, BUSUnderWriting, 
                WebPortalID, OFAC, WINSAccess, RequestedBy, RequestedDate, ReservePaymentAuth, DeptApprover, DepApprovalDate, ITApprover, ITApprovalDate, WINSPrimPolMgmt, 
                WINSPrimPremAcct, WINSPrimClaimMgmt, WINSPrimReinProc, WINSPrimMgmtInsInfo, WINSPrimMisc, WINSPrimPolInq, WINSPrimClaimInq, WINSPrimBillInq, WNPolMgmtBusOwn, WNPolMgmtBusAuto, 
                WNPolMgmtWrkComp, WNPolMgmtComUm, WNPolMgmtComPkgPol, WNPolMgmtComRec, WNPolMgmtPersRec, WNPolMgmtQuote, WNPolMgmtIssue, WNPolMgmtRenew, WNPolMgmtEndorse, WNPolMgmtCanNot, 
                WNPolMgmtFinCan, WNPolMgmtRein, WNPolMgmtRetro, WNPolMgmtRepEnd, WNPolMgmtNonMonEnd, WNPolMgmtAdd, WNPolMgmtChange, WNPolMgmtDelete, WNPolMgmtInquire, WNPolMgmtAddQuote, 
                WNPolMgmtAddCan, WNPrmAcctAccCurProc, WMPrmAcctChecks, WNPrmAcctDirBilProc, WNPrmAcctBillMaint, WNActCurProcControl, WNActCurProcEntry, WNActCurProcEntryAll, WNActCurProcLegal, WNActCurProcPrint, 
                WNActCurProcPost, WNActCurProcAdd, WNActCurProcChange, WNActCurProcDelete, WNActCurProcInquire, WNChkProcControl, WNChkProcEntry, WNChkProcPrCkEdLst, WNChkProcPrPstProdCk, WNChkProcPstManDiBil, 
                WNChkProcAcptCntrl, WNChkProcAcptEntry, WNChkProcPrtAcptCkEdLst, WNChkProcPstAcptCk, WNChkProcVoidStop, WNChkProcInvestigate, WNChkProcAdd, WNChkProcChange, WNChkProcDelete, WNChkProcInquire, 
                WNChkProcAcctCurr, WNChkProcDiBill, WNClmMgmtFstTrk, WMClmMgmtInClmEnt, WMClmMgmtClmEnt, WMClmMgmtAdjRes, WMClmMgmtChk, WMClmMgmtRec, WMClmMgmtLaw, WMClmMgmtDetClm, 
                WMClmMgmtArcExProc, WMClmChkMnIsPyCtl, WMClmChkMnIsPys, WMClmChkMnIsExCtl, WMClmChkMnIsExs, WMClmChkPrMnCkEdLs, WMClmChkPsMnChks, WMClmChkMaIsPys, WMClmChkMaIsExps, WMClmChkPrMaCkEdLs, 
                WMClmChkPrPsSyNmCks, WMClmChkPrPsPrNmChks, WMClmChkAcptCkCtrl, WMClmChkAcptCks, WMClmChkPrAcptCkEdLs, WMClmChkPsAcptChks, WMClmChkVdSpChks, WMClmChkCkInv, WMClmChkAutoAcptChks, 
                WMClmChkAdd, WMClmChkChange, WMClmChkDelete, WMClmChkInquire, WMReinPrcCoMaint, WMReinPrcIntMaint, WMReinPrcTrMaint, WMReinPrcPrgMaint, WMReinPrcCshCtl, WMReinPrcCshEntTr, 
                WMReinPrcCshEntFacPrm, WMReinPrcCshEntFacLos, WMReinPrcPrtReinCsh, WMReinPrcPsReinCsh, WMReinPrcOtReinPremEnt, WMReinPrcOtReinLosEnt, WMReinPrcAdd, WMReinPrcChange, WMReinPrcDelete, 
                WMReinPrcPrint, DateReqCreated, ReqCreatedBy, DateReqLastModified, ReqLastModifiedBy, UserPrimKey, CurrentLANID, CurrentWINSID, SpecialInstructions, VPNAccess, NCCIID, Virtru, MSAccessFull, 
                ISOClaimSearch, ISONet, ISOPassport, SanBornMaps, RProgramming, 0, Experian, WMClmMgmtAuth, WMClmMgmtLossCorr, GoogleEarth, Concur, 
                CutePDF, DIDyn, DIDNumber, Intern, PartTime, LeaveOfAbsence, PaymentAuth, PDErrorCorrect, EC500, PhoneBouncePattern, WebexMeetings, WebexTeams, BounceExtension,
                EC500Number, PowerBI, Tableau, UIPath, AllIN, RUR, ECase, ICInquiry, InvoiceExpenseAuth, International, DataHouseProd, DataHousePreProd, DataHouseTest, Zoom,
                PhysicalLocation, MSPowerApps, MSPowerAutomate, MSProject, MSVisio, Zendesk, 0, 0, 0, 0
    FROM
        NJSHAREPRDDB.GNYUserIDTracking.dbo.UserInformation
```

All the other tables work perfectly fine, but for this table, not all the columns match up. We added a few columns and deleted a few columns. That is why I couldn't use `*` and why you see 0 in the place of some of the column names.

I got a few errors messages prior that were column specific and I was able to fix them. Now, I am receiving this error message:

> String or binary data would be truncated

on the line for beginning of the `Select` statement and I don't know what a good strategy for figuring it out.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest to compare length of the involved varchar-columns

Comment: @Sergey can I get the name and length of the fields in a query?

Comment: I think I found it:

select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length    
  from information_schema.columns  
 where table_name = 'myTable'

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm